# Scrollspy active section not updating on navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, scrollspy

The active section on the scrollspy is not updating on the navbar. I'm not sure if I'm missing a script or if something in the code is wrong.

Script

```
    /* Navbar Spyscroll */
    $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navspy' })
    $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
      var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
    })
```

Code

```
<nav id="spynav" class="navbar navbar-light bg-transparent d-flex">
   <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#1">
   <img src="images/guy.png" alt="logo" style="width:85px;padding-bottom: 10px"></a>
   <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column align-self-center mx-auto">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#1">1</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#2">2</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#3">3</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#4">4</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#5">5</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#6">6</a>
      <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
         <a class="nav-link ml-3 my-1" href="#71">71</a>
         <a class="nav-link ml-3 my-1" href="#72">72</a>
         <a class="nav-link ml-3 my-1" href="#73">73</a>
      </nav>
   </nav>
</nav>
```

I expect the active section to follow on the navbar based on the scrollspy, but this get locked on #73 as soon as I start scrolling.

Comment: Can you create a full snippet that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Zim Not sure if I would be able to do that without sharing the whole code? I've recorded a .gif showing the behaviour https://imgur.com/bdvQqw2. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I've found. I hope it helps others.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').scrollspy({target: ".navbar"});
});
```